# How to configure a hypervisor such that a KVM/QEMU virtual machine can reach hosts connected to the same trunk bridge?

Tags: linux-networking, kvm-virtualization, vlan, bridge, libvirt

#### 1 Problem

My goal is that all LAN traffic is routed through a virtual machine (VM) acting as a router and firewall. Other VMs on the same hypervisor should also be routed through the firewall VM. See the following [network sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSorL.png). Physical hosts connected to the trunk bridge can ping each other successfully, but VMs could not be reached yet.

#### 2 Details

Network configuration on the hypervisor:

```
# =======
# Bridges
# =======
# ---------------------
# VLAN bridge br-vlan-3
# ---------------------
ip link add name br-vlan-3 type bridge
ip addr add 10.66.3.11/24 dev br-vlan-3
ip link set dev br-vlan-3 up

# ---------------------
# Trunk bridge Upstream
# ---------------------
ip link add name br-trunk-up type bridge vlan_filtering 1 vlan_default_pvid 0
ip link set br-trunk-up up

# ---------------
# Trunk bridge VM
# ---------------
ip link add name br-trunk-vm type bridge vlan_filtering 1 vlan_default_pvid 0
ip link set br-trunk-vm up

# =====
# Hosts
# =====

# Set physical devices up
ip link set enp5s0 up
ip link set enp9s0f0 up
ip link set enp9s0f1 up
ip link set enp9s0f2 up
ip link set enp9s0f3 up


# ----------------------
# desktop.3 br-vlan-3
# ----------------------
ip link add link enp9s0f1 name enp9s0f1.3 type vlan id 3
ip link set dev enp9s0f1.3 master br-vlan-3
ip link set enp9s0f1.3 up

# --------------------------
# desktop.100 br-trunk-vm
# --------------------------
ip link add link enp9s0f1 name enp9s0f1.100 type vlan id 100
ip link set enp9s0f1.100 master br-trunk-vm
ip link set enp9s0f1.100 up
bridge vlan add vid 100 dev enp9s0f1.100 master
bridge vlan add vid 100 dev br-trunk-vm self

bridge vlan add vid 100 dev fw.100 pvid 100
```

Network map

```
=======
DESKTOP
=======
localhost:user ~ $  ip a
2: enp34s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:d8:61:c4:b1:af brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: br-vlan-100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1a:b1:36:43:f0:e4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.66.100.44/24 scope global br-vlan-100
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: enp.100@enp34s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-vlan-100 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:d8:61:c4:b1:af brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    
localhost:~ # cat /proc/net/vlan/enp.100 
enp.100  VID: 100        REORDER_HDR: 1  dev->priv_flags: 1221
         total frames received            0
          total bytes received            0
      Broadcast/Multicast Rcvd            0

      total frames transmitted          287
       total bytes transmitted        53964
Device: enp34s0
INGRESS priority mappings: 0:0  1:0  2:0  3:0  4:0  5:0  6:0 7:0
 EGRESS priority mappings: 


==========
HYPERVISOR
==========
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br-vlan-100             8000.1ab13643f0e4       no              enp.100

[root@fedora system]# ip a  
4: enp9s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:36:9f:5d:09:19 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
13: br-trunk-vm: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 56:7e:22:6a:23:2d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
16: enp9s0f1.100@enp9s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-trunk-vm state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:36:9f:5d:09:19 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
21: fw.100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-trunk-vm state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:3e:97:72 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    
    
[root@fedora system]# brctl show dev br-trunk-vm
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br-trunk-vm             8000.567e226a232d       no              enp9s0f1.100
                                                        fw.100
                                                        fw.103
                                                        fw.3


===============
VIRTUAL MACHINE 
===============                                                                    
[root@fedora system]# bridge vlan show
port              vlan-id  
br-trunk-vm       100
enp9s0f1.100      100
virbr0            1 PVID Egress Untagged
fw.100            100 PVID Egress Untagged


2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:3e:97:72 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.66.100.10/24 scope global enp1s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Libvirt XML network configuration of the firewall VM:

```
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='52:54:00:3e:97:72'/>
  <source bridge='br-trunk-vm'/>
  <target dev='fw.100'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

#### 3 Attempts

I tried configuring both a tagged and untagged NIC on the firewall VM. For the tagged NIC I created a VLAN bridge on the firewall VM and created a virtual tap device from the virtual tap `fw.100` with the VLAN 100: `vlan100@fw.100`. Then I set the trunk port of `vlan100@fw.100` to master: `bridge vlan add vid 100 dev vlan100@fw.100 master`. For the untagged NIC approach I configured no VLAN on the firewall VM and set its trunk port to PVID 100 untagged `bridge vlan add vid 100 dev fw.100 pvid 100 untagged`. In both cases I could not ping between the desktop host and the firewall VM.

This issue happens only with the libvirt KVM/QEMU virtual machine. Two physical VLAN tagged hosts connected to the hypervisor's trunk bridge as master can ping each other.

#### 4 Update

It looks like that libvirt does not support Linux bridges with VLANs. According to following article the VMs VLAN stops working if there is a second virtual device on the hypervisor with the same VLAN: https://alesnosek.com/blog/2015/09/07/bridging-vlan-trunk-to-the-guest/

Alternatively openvswitch can be used, yet using a bridge for each VM and physical host is a better approach. The hypervisor then allows forwarding the VMs' and hosts' bridges to the firewall VM's bridge and the remaining routing is then done inside the firewall's VM.

Comment: Yes, libvirt does not support setting vlans for VMs with vlan-aware Linux bridge. Shame on them. The best you can do is to set up VLANs on the virtual bridge ports that belong to VMs by hand with `bridge` utility after the VM is started.